# How to change template for filenameHashing?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

how can I change template for

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = defineConfig({
 filenameHashing: true,
})
```

For example, original filenameHashing looks like `app.b1d1061b.css`
but I wanna there to be only [contentHash].[ext] for example `b1d1061b.css`
How can I do this?

I tried to disable   `filenameHashing: false,` and

```
output: {
      filename: "[contenthash].js",
    },
```

but this didn't work for other pages (Vue router)

```
 dist\e08fab3efc717cf1.js
 dist\66c38f6c984978f2.js
 dist\js\about.js
```